# Sawtooth wave generation not perfect

Tags: circuit-design, sawtooth-waveform

[image]

Here is my schematic for a sawtooth wave generator with a potentiometer to control the frequency. The sawtooth output is not a perfect shape.

How can I improve my circuit to make a more true sawtooth wave?

Comment: What about the sawtooyh is not perfect?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "perfect". My advice is, find the Fourier series of an ideal sawtooth and base your specification off of that. (i.e. difference in harmonic magnitude difference is less than 1% for the first 5 harmonics).

Answer (score 3):

It looks a pretty good sawtooth to me!

Which aspects are you concerned about?

- Little steps on the slope? That's an artifact of the simulator, a real physical circuit would not have those.
- Retrace not vertical enough? You would need to improve the Schmidt trigger inverter, its speed and/or output current capability.
- Slopes not linear enough? One option would be to improve your current source into the capacitor. The Early effect on that transistor changes the sink current with the collector voltage, so cascoding it through another stage will help.

An alternative way to improve slope linearity is to use the capacitor in the feedback of a virtual ground amplifier, another way to make your current source feed a node at constant voltage.

Your output RC will also have a small effect on slope linearity at low frequencies.

I notice that the use of two transistors, the first to compensate the VBE of the second, makes the voltage -> frequency relationship much more thermally stable than would be the case with a single transistor, so somebody has taken some thought about the circuit.